# Descriptive analyses of repeated measures data

Tags: repeated-measures, descriptive-statistics

I have a dataset with repeated measures of a continuous outcome in a closed cohort of individuals at multiple timepoints that are equally spaced. Beyond the use of the mean, median, outlier identification, and the identification of trends (visually), are there other descriptive analyses that one can perform on these data?

Additionally, how would I compare the means at two different timepoints? Assuming that the assumptions are met, would it be appropriate to do a one-way ANOVA with repeated measures?

Comment: Absolutely.  You could carry out mixed modeling and generalized estimating equations models.

Comment: Does it make a difference if the design of the study is a stepped-wedged RCT? Would the one-way ANOVA still be valid (if the assumptions are met)?